# Lenovo RD640 RAID-5 Expansion

Tags: hard-drive, raid5, lenovo

I have a Lenovo RD640 server configured for 2.5" drives. I have a RAID-5 array with  3 x Seagate 600GB 10K SAS 2.5” (ST600MM0006). I urgently need to expand the RAID as a temporary measure, but apparently these drives are EOL and no longer supplied by the vendor. I've never mixed non-identical disks, but feel like that's my only option.

Can this be done, and if so which replacement drives could be added the the existing array?